# enum + switch ( свой пример )

Tags: java, switch, enum

```
public enum Apple {
    SAL, TES, ULP, GESL
}


public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Apple ap = Apple.GESL;
            String text;
            switch (ap){
                case TES:
                    System.out.println("Неправильно - 1");
                    text = "Tes";
                    break;
                case SAL:
                    System.out.println("Неправильно - 2");
                    text = "Sal";
                    break;
                case ULP:
                    System.out.println("Неправильно - 3");
                    text = "Ulp";
                    break;
                case GESL:
                    System.out.println("Правильно");
                    text = "Gesl";
                    break;
            }
            System.out.println(text);  // Здесь компилятор ругается (Variable 'text' might not have been initialized) не понимаю почему ругается?
        }
    }
```

Не понимаю почему text в sout(e) подсвечивает красным и не работает программа, подсказка пишет:

```
Variable 'text' might not have been initialized
```

НО когда добавляем вот этот кусочек кода, default, то ошибка уходит:

```
                default:
                System.out.println("Ну как-то так");
                text = "default";
                break;
```

То есть вот так:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Apple ap = Apple.GESL;
        String text;
        switch (ap) {
            case TES:
                System.out.println("Неправильно - 1");
                text = "Tes";
                break;
            case SAL:
                System.out.println("Неправильно - 2");
                text = "Sal";
                break;
            case ULP:
                System.out.println("Неправильно - 3");
                text = "Ulp";
                break;
            case GESL:
                System.out.println("Правильно");
                text = "Gesl";
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Ну как-то так");
                text = "default";
                break;
        }
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте defaut в switch. Компилятор выдает ошибку, потому что text будет не инициализирована, если в switch не будет подходящего case.

Comment: А что Вам не понятно?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ почему с дефолтом работает, а без нет. Почему вообще ошибку выдает?

Comment: компилятор определил, что возможно состояние, когда переменная может `text` быть не инициализирована при выходе из switch и предупредил Вас об этом.

Answer (score 0):

Переменная, объявленная в методе должна быть инициализирована
`String text = null;` или 
`String text = "";`

Comment: напишите тогда уж развернутый ответ, иначе это больше похоже на комментарий

Comment: String text = ''; так нельзя